# Strategy Pattern implementing Prim's Algorithm

Tags: java, dijkstra, strategy-pattern, prims-algorithm

I am using Dijkstra's Algorithm for a project but want to try to use Strategy Pattern implementing Prims algorithm to see what is it better, but I am unsure how go about using the Strategy Pattern. I have never used patterns before so I do not know where to start.

```
package wpi.cs509.routeFinder;

import wpi.cs509.dataModel.*;
import wpi.cs509.dataManager.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;

public class RouteFinder {

public static ArrayList<Point> computePaths(Point source, Graph g, Point destination)
{
    if(source.getId()==destination.getId()){
        ArrayList<Point> point=new ArrayList<Point>();
        point.add(source);
        return point;
    }
    source.minDistance = 0;
    PriorityQueue<Point> pointQueue = new PriorityQueue<Point>();
    pointQueue.add(source);

while (!pointQueue.isEmpty()) {
    Point u = pointQueue.poll();

        // Visit each edge exiting u
        for (Edge e : g.getNeighbors(u))
        {
            Point v = g.getPointById(e.getePointId()!=u.getId()?e.getePointId():e.getsPointId());
            float weight = e.getWeight();
            double distanceThroughU = u.minDistance + weight;
    if (distanceThroughU < v.minDistance) {
        pointQueue.remove(v);
        v.minDistance = distanceThroughU ;
        v.previous = u;
        pointQueue.add(v);
      //  System.out.println("u.id is"+u.getId());
            }
        }
    }
return getShortestPathTo(g.getPointById(destination.getId()));

}

public static ArrayList<Point> getShortestPathTo(Point destination)
{
    ArrayList<Point> path = new ArrayList<Point>();
    for (Point vertex = destination; vertex != null; vertex = vertex.previous)
    { 
        path.add(vertex);
    }

    Collections.reverse(path);
    return path;
}



public static void main(String[] args){
    Graph g = new Graph();
    ArrayList<Point> p = new ArrayList<Point>();
    //g=DataManager.getGraphByNameWithDB("testLab",2);
    Point source = new Point();
    source.setId(11);
    source.setX(111);
    source.setY(222);
    source.setBuildingName("testLab");
    source.setFloorNum(2);
    source.setMapEntrance(false);
    source.setDestination(true);
    source.setName("source");


    Point end = new Point();
    end.setId(15);
    end.setX(161);
    end.setY(616);
    end.setBuildingName("testLab");
    end.setFloorNum(2);
    end.setMapEntrance(false);
    end.setDestination(true);
    end.setName("end");

    p=computePaths(source,g,end);
    System.out.println(p.size());
    for(int i =0;i<p.size();i++)
    {
        System.out.println("result is "+p.get(i).getId());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to use the Strategy pattern for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy pattern is meant to put the algorithm into a class, where the data is assured to be the same, such that the algorithm can be reused against multiple copies of data without creating new instances of the strategy to handle them.

Unless you really need this behavior,  I recommend you do not use the strategy pattern to start, as this weakens the object-oriented design in a way (by separating data and behavior).

Instead, try a Route interface, with two implementations `DikstraRoute` and `PimsRoute`.  Then, your top level code will only deal with `Route`s, and not need to deal with their implementations.

The interface

```
public interface Route {
   public ArrayList<Point> getPath();
}
```

Your constructors might look like

```
public DikstraRoute implements Route {
   public DikstraRoute(Point start, Graph g, Point destination) {
     ...
   }

   @Override
   public ArrayList<Point> getPath() {
     ...
   }
}

public PimsRoute implements Route {
   public PimsRoute(Point start, Graph g, Point destination) {
     ...
   }

   @Override
   public ArrayList<Point> getPath() {
     ...
   }
}
```

and the interface is what guarantees the "getPath()" operation.

It's an object-oriented language, might want to write a few objects every now and then.  An all-static way of programming will not provide you with any kind of maintenance benefits over time (so it might as well be C).

If you find (after hitting this intermediate) that you really need a strategy after all, then move the objects you passed to the constructor into the method in the interface.  Cut any internal fields you had in the previous (above) solution, and you will have converted your `Route` object to a `Route` strategy.  Remember, if your object contains only code, but no state, it is effectively a strategy.

To demonstrate, the strategy approach would look like

The interface

```
public interface Route {
   public ArrayList<Point> getPath(Point start, Graph g, Point destination);
}
```

Your constructors might look like

```
public DikstraRoute implements Route {
   public DikstraRoute() {
     ...
   }

   @Override
   public ArrayList<Point> getPath(Point start, Graph g, Point destination) {
     ...
   }
}

public PimsRoute implements Route {
   public PimsRoute() {
     ...
   }

   @Override
   public ArrayList<Point> getPath(Point start, Graph g, Point destination) {
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Just a quick note.  You can't do strategies with out objects.  This means you need to push your logic into objects either way.  Static is not a friend of maintainable Java.